# How to check the presence of preceding string to another string and get file name from the HTML data in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, associative-array

I've an array associative array titled `$comments` as follows :

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
            (
                [text] => Uploading Photo  for comment <div class="comment_attach_image">

    <a title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

    <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

    </div>                
            )
    [1] => Array
            (
                [text] => <div class="comment_attach_file">

    <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI" >pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI</a>

    <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI" >Download</a>
    </div>
            )
     [2] => Array
            (  
                [text] => This comment is of two lines need to check more about it                
            )
    )
```

I want to do two operations on each element from the above array.

**First thing** I want to check whether any string(text) is present before the `<div>` tag. Like in first element the text **'Uploading Photo  for comment'** is present before the `<div>` tag whereas in second element it doesn't. If such text is present assign it to some variable and it should be stored in a key [text] of array `$comments` else the key `[text]` of array `$comments` should contain null.

**Second thing** I want is to get the file name from the HTML data. Like for first array element it should be **CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4** and for second element it should be **pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI**. This file name should be stored in a key `[file_name]` of array `$comments` else the key `[file_name]` of array `$comments` should contain null.

If the array element is like third array element i.e. not containing any HTML just the simple text nothing should happen.

How should I achieve these two things in an efficient manner? The actual array could contain hundreds of such elements.

I tried following code but it's not returning me the file name and when the preceding string is missing it returns me garbage HTML into key text. For your reference I'm putting below my code.

```
 foreach($comments as $key=>$comment) {
    $text = strstr($comment['text'], '<div');
    if (strlen($text) <= 0) {
      $comments[$key]['type_id'] =  'text';
      $comments[$key]['url'] =  '';
      $comments[$key]['text'] =  $comment['text'];
    } else if($xml = @simplexml_load_string($text)) { 
      $comments[$key]['type_id'] =  substr(strrchr($xml['class'], '_'), 1);
      $comments[$key]['url'] = str_replace(array('href=','"'), '',$xml->a['href']->asXML());
      $comments[$key]['text'] =  strtok($comment['text'], '<');           
    } else {
      continue;
    }    
  }
```

P.S. : Please look at the minor differences in both the element's HTML. Please consider these differences in order to do the two operations I mentioned.

Thanks.

Comment: when parsing HTML strings, you should always consider using HTML parsers, `DOMDocument` in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what I have said in the comments, this task (HTML Parsing) is much easier to manage when HTML parsers are used. Don't use string functions for this. This is what they are designed for.

In this example, `DOMDocument` class is used:

```
$comments = array(
    array('text' => 'Uploading Photo  for comment <div class="comment_attach_image">

        <a title="colorbox" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" ><img src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" height="150px" width="150px" /></a>

        <a href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/CnYTVQdATAOQTkMxpAq4" class="comment_attach_image_link_dwl">Download</a>

        </div>'
    ),
    array('text' => '<div class="comment_attach_file">

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI" >pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI</a>

        <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pxRBwNBcSueP0hf1meOI" >Download</a>
        </div>'
    ),
);

$data = array();

foreach($comments as $c) {
    $temp = array();
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML(trim($c['text']));
    $first = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->firstChild;


    $file = $first->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
    $url = $file->getAttribute('href');


    if($first->tagName != 'div') {
        // not div
        $not_div = $first->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
        $type = explode('_', $not_div->getAttribute('class'));
        $type = end($type);
        $temp['type_id'] = $type;
        $temp['url'] = $url;
        $temp['file_name'] = basename($url);
        $temp['text'] = $c['text'];

    } else {
        // div
        $type = explode('_', $first->getAttribute('class'));
        $type = end($type);
        $temp['type_id'] = $type;
        $temp['url'] = $url;
        $temp['file_name'] = basename($url);
        $temp['text'] = '';
    }

    $data[] = $temp;
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($data, 1), '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not getting the file name for second array element. Also the preceding text checking and new array key creation is missing from the code. If you read my question again you'll realize what is missing in the answer to be called it as a complete answer. If you could give me the complete answer it would be really helpful to me. With the final array.

Comment: @PHPNut oh okay, shouldn't be much of a change, i'l revise this in a bit

Comment: :Thanks. My final output array should contain these text and file_name keys that's what my ultimate goal is. So you make your changes accordingly. Thanks once again.

Comment: @PHPNut i have made the necessary changes (if i understood you correctly), anyway, i can't setup a demo codepad.viper-7.com seems down right now

Comment: Thank you so much for your immense help. Just small correction. In key [type_id] for first element it should come as image(i.e. the last word from the string comment_attach_file)  and for second element it should come as file(i.e. the last word from the string comment_attach_file). Also for first array element the [url] and [file_name] keys are blank. In fact they should contain the respective file_name and URL. Can you make these small corrections to your code please? Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I'm waiting your reply sir.

Comment: You are the gem man. I don't have words to say thanks to you. I will always remain in your debt Ghost. Thank you so much once again for helping me out. Accepted and upovoted your answer.